# "cannot open linker script file" when compiling GameKit for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mips

When I built Gamekit for Android, I got the follow error:

```
...(deleted)
[ 98%] Built target OgreKitCore
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/StripBlend
/usr/local/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/mipsel-linux-android/4.6.x-google/../../../../mipsel-linux-android/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file /usr/local/android-ndk/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/mipself.x: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/StripBlend] Error 1
make[1]: *** [FileTools/Strip/CMakeFiles/StripBlend.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I google it and found a related post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doubango/TVOUjTxfbtA/y6eaikfcTu0J
They just rollback NDK version to fix this problem.

However, I have to build an Android Gamekit library for MIPS CPU, so I need NDK-r8 or NDK-r8b.

Is there any suggestion to fix this problem?

PS: GameKit is http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy mipself.x and mipself.xsc, which can be downloaded from the Internet,
into /toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/ folder, and then fix this problem.